Is there a way to backup a keyspace and restore it to a different cluster?
I have a live cassandra cluster(One node).  I've built out a 3 node cluster I would like to migrate a keyspace to the new cluster.  Is there a way to backup a Key space, then restore that Key space into a different Cassandra cluster?

It is a relatively simple process to clone the keyspace to another cluster using the sstableloader utility that ships with Cassandra.
The high-level steps are:

Create a snapshot of the keyspace.
For each table in the keyspace, clone the snapshot to another cluster using sstableloader.
Repeat step 2 until all tables have been cloned.

The detailed steps are in How do I migrate data in tables to a new Cassandra cluster?. Cheers!
